# How do I do a screenshot of the desktop cube?

Tags: compiz, screenshot, cube

Is there a way to do a screenshot of the rotating cube? I can't get it to work while I am rotating the cube.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applications > Accessories > Take Screenshot

Where it says "Grab after a delay of [0    ] seconds"
Change the delay to say 5 seconds, then go into the cube mode. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left Mouse Button, then hold it for 5 seconds.

When you return to a workspace you will see the screenshot window offering to save.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal drop:

```
gnome-screenshot -d 10
```

Where: 10 is the amount of seconds you wish the screenshot to wait before be taken. You can change this value to any amount of time as you wish.

After hitting [Enter], do whatever you wish and wait for the screenshot to be taken.

Good luck.